# Как работает текст «Залго»?

Tags: unicode

Что это за строка и в чём её смысл?

> H̡̫̤̤̣͉̤ͭ̓̓̇͗̎̀ơ̯̗̱̘̮͒̄̀̈ͤ̀͡w͓̲͙͖̥͉̹͋ͬ̊ͦ̂̀̚ ͎͉͖̌ͯͅͅd̳̘̿̃̔̏ͣ͂̉̕ŏ̖̙͋ͤ̊͗̓͟͜e͈͕̯̮̙̣͓͌ͭ̍̐̃͒s͙͔̺͇̗̱̿̊̇͞ ̸̤͓̞̱̫ͩͩ͑̋̀ͮͥͦ̊Z̆̊͊҉҉̠̱̦̩͕ą̟̹͈̺̹̋̅ͯĺ̡̘̹̻̩̩͋͘g̪͚͗ͬ͒o̢̖͇̬͍͇͓̔͋͊̓ ̢͈͙͂ͣ̏̿͐͂ͯ͠t̛͓̖̻̲ͤ̈ͣ͝e͋̄ͬ̽͜҉͚̭͇ͅx͎̬̠͇̌ͤ̓̂̓͐͐́͋͡ț̗̹̝̄̌̀ͧͩ̕͢ ̮̗̩̳̱̾w͎̭̤͍͇̰̄͗ͭ̃͗ͮ̐o̢̯̻̰̼͕̾ͣͬ̽̔̍͟ͅr̢̪͙͍̠̀ͅǩ̵̶̗̮̮ͪ́?̙͉̥̬͙̟̮͕ͤ̌͗ͩ̕͡

Comment: [How does Zalgo text work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Comment: @Никита, я взял на себя смелость очень сильно отредактировать ваш вопрос. Это было необходимо, чтобы он стал соответствовать допустимой тематике сайта. Если у вас есть какие-то уточняющие вопросы, задавайте их в комментариях! )

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, как ломающий человеческое форматирование страницы! :)

Comment: Не, хорошо теперь, можно открывать. @NickVolynkin сделал хороший ответ на который посылать всех с подобными вопросами.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А пока пусть пойдёт на линковку с английской версией: [пара  номером 60](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/213987)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Есть предложение вот ещё какое. Можно всё уже учесть замечание alexolut о поломанном формтировании страницы и взять строчку из английского вопроса (перевести на русский + наклепать диакритики), надеюсь, топикстартер не в обиде будет.

Comment: @AK сделано (наполовину)

Comment: @AK в следующий раз, когда увижу "на Stack Overflow подавляют новичков, ничего нельзя сделать, сложно набрать первую репутацию" — буду отправлять всех смотреть на Никиту, который  набрал сотню, даже не регистрируясь. :)

Comment: @AK "Вопросу уделили недостаточно внимания" Вы это серьёзно?

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Answer (score 56):

Эта строка написана с использованием *комбинируемых символов Юникода*. А Юникод — это такая система для кодирования вообще всех возможных элементов любой письменности, которая существует сейчас, существовала когда-то (мертвые языки) и даже для некоторых выдуманных (например, клингонского языка). В Юникоде больше ста тысяч символов<sup>1</sup> и у каждого есть свой номер, который записывается так: U+<шестнадцатеричное число>. Например, латинская буква A<sup>2</sup> — это [U+0041](https://unicode-table.com/ru/0041/).

В письменности множества языков есть *диакритические символы* — это значки, которые добавляются к букве и в результате получается либо новая буква (е → ё), либо какой-то дополнительный смысл той же буквы (например, ударение).

Таких значков очень много: фантазия человечества придумала десятки кружочков, крючочков, точек, чёрточек и прочего. Очень сложно было бы вместить в стандарт сочетание каждого из этих значков с каждой возможной буквой. Поэтому были придуманы и разработаны комбинируемые символы.

Работает это вот так. Есть латинская буква `A`. Нам нужно написать эту букву с кружочком наверху, чтобы получилось `Å`. Для этого, мы используем базовую букву `A`, а после неё ставим комбинируемый символ `˚` – [U+030A «Комбинируемый надстрочный кружок»](https://unicode-table.com/ru/030A/)<sup>3</sup>. Фактически *эти символы идут раздельно* один за другим, но браузер (или текстовый редактор) умеет их комбинировать, поэтому *показывает их вместе*.

Комбинируемые символы могут добавляться не только сверху, но и снизу: A͢, и даже прямо поверх символа:  ̸А. Можно даже сразу везде:   ̸Å͢.

Что произойдёт, если после одного «базового» символа поставить мнооого комбинируемых? Получится столбик символов, вот такой:  Å̊̊̊̊̊̊̊̊. Именно так и устроен «Залго»-текст.

---

Текст выше написан насколько возможно простым языком и содержит ряд фактических неточностей. Ниже — примечания для профессионалов.

1. На самом деле, не символов, а кодовых позиций (code points), которым назначен (assigned/designated) какой-то абстрактный символ (abstract character) или другая роль. Всего возможных кодовых позиций 1114112<sub>10</sub> или 17×2<sup>16</sup> (от `0` до `U+10FFFF`) и большинству пока что ничего не назначено.
2. На самом деле, `A` следует называть абстрактным символом (abstract character), которому назначена кодовая позиция U+0041. Абстрактный символ содержит в себе только идею буквы A, но не определяет какое-то конкретное отображение (glyph). Конкретные изображения содержатся в шрифтах.
3. Это не единственный способ получить абстрактный символ `Å`. Две кодовых позиции Юникода назначены непосредственно этому символу: [Латинская заглавная буква A с кружочком сверху U+00C5](https://unicode-table.com/ru/00C5/) и  [Знак ангстрема U+212B](https://unicode-table.com/ru/212B/). Это далеко не исключение, многие абстрактные символы имеют назначенные кодовые позиции (1 или более) и «собираются» с помощью комбинируемых символов. Все абстрактные символы, которым назначены собственные кодовые позиции, называются *assigned characters*.

Аналогичный вопрос на английском: [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Comment: Пришлось задуматься над конструкцией 1,114,112. В русских текстах запятая является разделителем десятичной части, но никак не разрядов. На некоторое время сложилось впечатление, что это три отдельных числа.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev спасибо, вы совершенно правы. Убрал запятые, уточнил систему счисления. Так оставить или ещё что-нибудь поправить?

Comment: Вторая часть вопроса: в чём смысл? Иными словами, для чего используется Залго-текст. Для проверки подсистемы отображения Unicode-символов?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko кажется, чаще всего это используется для того, чтобы пугать технически неграмотных людей. :)

Comment: @MarkShevchenko считаете, стоит подробнее написать об использовании?

Comment: Для карма...... даже не смогли найти другую строку, а прямо скопипастили из английского вопроса.

Comment: @Nakilon репутация за вопрос идет Никите, а не мне. :) А репутацию за ответ я считаю заслуженной, я написал его полностью сам, потому что разбираюсь в теме.

Comment: @Nakilon дайте рядом свой ответ, я вас тоже плюсану. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Просто вторая часть вопроса "в чём её смысл?". Я почему то думал, что в этих строках действительно есть какой-то смысл, и тогда его надо было бы наверное раскрыть. Но сейчас пошерстил — оказалось, это просто один из глупых мемов.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko да, всё именно так. Можно было бы дать ссылку на Лурк, но я лучше не буду.