# Некорректная обработка IndexOf или же нет?

Tags: c#, строки, unicode

Данный код возвращает 0, хотя по документации должен возвращать -1. Я что-то не правильно делаю? Версия .NET - 4.7.1.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Dddd".IndexOf("⚽️", 0));
```

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести. У меня выдает -1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow у меня 0 выдает

Comment: @VladfromMoscow попробуйте перегрузку с указанием культуры `Console.WriteLine("Dddd".IndexOf("⚽️", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: @tym32167 мне не помогло. Интересная штука, конечно

Comment: Джон Скит [писал](https://habr.com/en/post/165597/), что некоторые юникодные символы ломают `.IndexOf`. Смотри его ссылку на [рекомендации по обработке строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973919(v=msdn.10)). Также вспоминается [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23770869/5752652) прикол.

Comment: Действительно, лучше будет перевести символ в unicode и сравнить его

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вам и не должно было помочь, я просто посоветовал как воспроизвести это.

Comment: `StringComparison.Ordinal` помогает вернуть `-1`. Ordinal - простое побайтовое сравнение. Думаю, оно будет работать всегда. А то понапридумывали культур-мультур...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Также вспоминается [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23770869/5752652) неочевидный "баг". И [такой](https://habr.com/en/company/ruvds/blog/445274/), буквально на днях на хабре опять мелькнуло. В общем, строки — это не так просто, а когда дело доходит до обработки тонкостей юникода это становится ещё сложнее.

Вообще, Джон Скит [писал](https://habr.com/en/post/165597/), что некоторые юникодные символы ломают `.IndexOf`.

Смотри его ссылку на [рекомендации по обработке строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973919(v=msdn.10)).

Если вам нужно, чтобы работало в соответствии с рекомендациями, то необходимо указывать культуру строки.

Вообще, у вас в строке два символа. Один — это собственно то, что мы видим глазом:

⚽   e2 9a bd

А вот второй — невидимый, но если вы выделите его в Linqpad, то видно будет что есть ещё один:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Можете проверить — любого из них достаточно, чтобы сломать IndexOf)

Ещё лучше видно через специализируемые инструменты, [наподобие такого](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%9A%BD%EF%B8%8F).

Это признак комбинирования символа через [Variation Selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)), почти такой же как и  [комбинируемые символамы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

Пример использования можете посмотреть в [вопросе про текст Zalgo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612002/213987).

Comment: так и не понял, почему `IndexOf` вернул 0

Comment: @4per В коде на c# этого не видно, т.к. буквально через пару обёрток string.IndexOf -> CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf решарпер утыкается в неуправляемый код ([DllImport("QCall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9491337/5752652)). Если у кого-то есть знания чтобы добраться до этого уровня - я бы с удовольствием почитал, как там выглядит на таком низком уровне.